# Creating btrfs subvolume like @ or @home

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, btrfs

Being intrigued by btrfs I decided to toy around with it in a VM. Installation works great as long as I remember to put `/boot` on a separate partition and it all seems to work fine.

What I would like to do is create a separate subvolume for bulk data with different settings than things like `@` and `@home`. `btrfs subvolume create data` will do that for me, but I'm curious why it keeps naming it `@/data` (or similar things when I try `/data` or `@data`). Is there a special way to create the subvolumes like `@` and `@home` so my data subvolume will show up as `@data`? (and: what is the exact difference between the naming schemes?)

---

Additional information:

- ubuntu 12.04.2, running as a KVM guest on mint15 host;
- kernel 3.8.0-27-generic from ubuntu-x-swat (raring backport);
- btrfs using two devices, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`
- `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are partitions on a disk not used by the host OS

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Sigh*, seems I posted a bit too soon, with a bit of help of the almighty Zosma on IRC, we found out how this is supposed to work.

Subvolumes `@` and `@home` are children of the btrfs root, so `/` is not actually the root of the file system. The UUID of the btrfs root is supplied in `/etc/fstab` twice, providing the mounts for `/` and `/home`. Mounting the actual root of the file system shows the subvolumes created by the installer:

```
root@box:~# mkdir /mnt/btrfs
root@box:~# mount UUID=f8963df3-1320-4bc0-a125-62be185b029e /mnt/btrfs
root@box:~# ls /mnt/btrfs
@  @home
```

So that's where they went! Creating a new subvolume in the exact way the ubuntu installer did is now easy:

```
root@box:~# btrfs subvolume create /mnt/btrfs/@data
Create subvolume '/mnt/btrfs/@data'
```

Now, as we've created a subvolume in the btrfs root instead of in the root filesystem for the install, `/data/` won't show up by itself. Luckily, it's trivial to copy the trick used by the installer by examining `/etc/fstab` and add another mount for `/data`:

```
UUID=f8963df3-1320-4bc0-a125-62be185b029e /data  btrfs  defaults,subvol=@data 0 2
```

Last step is to create the mount point: `mkdir /data`. After a reboot, we'll have a `/data` directory mounted from a separate btrfs subvolume.

… Profit!

Answer (score 5):

> Installation works great as long as I remember to put /boot on a separate partition

You do not need to have a separate /boot. GRUB2 can read and boot Linux from a btrfs.

> What I would like to do is create a separate subvolume for bulk data with different settings than things like @ and @home.

If you're talking about mounting subvolumes with different [mount options](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mount_options), be aware that currently (Nov 2013) they are not supported: according to the Btrfs FAQ, "[Can I mount subvolumes with different mount options?](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_mount_subvolumes_with_different_mount_options.3F)", currently only the btrfs-specific options are not supported or not implemented. However, the developers have plans to implement it in the future.

> btrfs subvolume create data will do that for me, but I'm curious why it keeps naming it @/data (or similar things when I try /data or @data)

By default, Ubuntu's installer Ubiquity creates subvolumes `@` and `@home` in the filesystem, and your Ubuntu root is actually in the subvolume `@`.

> Is there a special way to create the subvolumes like @ and @home so my data subvolume will show up as @data? (and: what is the exact difference between the naming schemes?)

`@` and `@home` are arbitrary names chosen by the installer, that have no meaning outside `/etc/fstab`. In fact, I typically rename them to more specific names, so that I can have many Ubiquity-installed distros on the same btrfs, as long as I remember to update their fstab's.

More subvolume explanation at [Funtoo.org - BTRFS](http://www.funtoo.org/BTRFS_Fun#Playing_with_subvolumes_and_snapshots).

Comment: Thanks for a thorough addition here; lots of useful information :)

Comment: @ and @home are also useful to make timeshift work (to take snapshots)