# create '@' like subvolume in another partition

Tags: btrfs

I have /var/log as a btrfs filesystem in a separate partition from root.  I'm using snapshots for update and will later rollback.

```
# mount
/dev/sda2 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,subvol=@)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda2 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,subvol=@home)
/dev/sda3 on /var/log type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd)

# fstab
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
LABEL=root      /               btrfs   relatime,ssd,subvol=@ 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
LABEL=boot      /boot           ext2    relatime        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda2 during installation
LABEL=root      /home           btrfs   relatime,ssd,subvol=@home 0       2
# /var/log was on /dev/sda3 during installation
LABEL=log       /var/log        btrfs   relatime,ssd    0       2
```

Everything works fine for my root partition, the problem is with my log partition.  Any snapshots I create in /var/log are visible in the /var/log directory and I can't figure out how to rollback the /var/log snapshot.  I like the way the root partition hides the subvols and I'd like to do the same for log partition.

Here's my root and log partitions with some snapshots

```
[~]$ sudo btrfs subvolume list /
ID 257 gen 3165 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 3142 top level 5 path @home
ID 262 gen 2086 top level 5 path fr-root
ID 263 gen 2086 top level 5 path fr-home
[~]$ sudo btrfs subvolume list /var/log
ID 257 gen 519 top level 5 path fr-log
```

Since there is no '@log' to create the fr-log snapshot i had to:

```
sudo mount -L log /mnt/up
sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot /var/log /mnt/up/fr-log
```

Instead of creating from the mount like I did for root:

```
sudo mount -L root /mnt/up
sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt/up/@ /mnt/up/fr-root
```

I tried the steps here [Creating btrfs subvolume like @ or @home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331233/creating-btrfs-subvolume-like-or-home) but my edits to fstab would cause the box to fail on boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I got the needed results from my preseed in-target install script:

```
# create @log subvolume for mounting /var/log
# this is kludgy but since preseed didn't provide a way...
# this the only way i could create a hidden '@' handle for the /var/log partition 
if [ ! -d /mnt ]; then mkdir /mnt; fi
mount -L log /mnt
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@log
mv -f /var/log/* /mnt/@log/ || true
umount /mnt
while read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ "LABEL=log" ]]; then
        echo "LABEL=log       /var/log        btrfs   relatime,ssd,subvol=@log    0       2" >> /tmp/fstab
    else
        echo "$line" >> /tmp/fstab
    fi
done < /etc/fstab
cp -v /tmp/fstab /etc/fstab
btrfs subvolume list /
btrfs subvolume list /var/log
```